What is the secret new mechanic in MUG ?
I've been playing MUG  for the last couple of days and in one of the release notes, they state the following:

ONE SECRET MECHANIC


Well, it's secret... Just click and you'll see.

But I've clicked all over the place. I can't find anything. What is the secret mechanic?

Solaire of Astoria (discuss button in the patch notes you gave) notes: I am over 532,000 mugs in at around 7.1 hours in. I am unsure what the secret mechanic is but the passive mugs are pretty much doing all the work for me now.
